# Is there a specific rule that says that comparing languages is off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is there a specific rule that says that comparing languages is off-topic?

These days, questions comparing languages are getting closed, but a few years ago, that wasn't the case.

For example, my question about Swift vs OCaml got closed (and deleted), but [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699689/what-are-the-differences-between-sml-and-ocaml) about SML vs OCaml got 81 upvotes in 2009, and the best answer got 136 upvotes.

Is there a specific, official rule that forbids such comparisons?

Call me a cynic, but it feels like SO got a bit too popular with people who just use it to get freelance jobs, and they jostle for status here. If they know Sift, say, but they don't know OCaml, their knee-jerk reaction is to close questions they can't answer that appear in "their" tag.

By the way, I'm voting to re-open the linked question (someone closed it after I linked to it). I think it's very useful to people studying either SML or OCaml.

**Edit** [the supposedly similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333471/comparing-programming-languages) is about **stating** some differences between languages (as in a blog post), not about asking questions about said differences. My question is obviously different from that one.

**Edit2** Why is **this** question getting downvoted and closed too? It's **clearly** not a dupe. Just click on the other question and read it. Don't just go by the title.

Comment: Most of the language comparison questions I see get closed because they're not really asking something specific enough. They basically come down to "which one is better," so they're a combination of too broad and opinion-based. I don't think questions comparing languages are inherently off-topic. I think it just depends on the scope of the comparison.

Comment: Incidentally, really old questions generally aren't dependable examples of current on-topic-ness.

Comment: see [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) -- _"if you... don't want your question to get instantly closed... - try to keep Gorilla vs. Shark in mind."_

Comment: *"see Gorilla vs. Shark"* -- Sorry, straw man. Gorilla vs Shark is not a practically useful example. On the other hand, knowing the differences between SML and OCaml is practically useful if you are deciding whether to learn or use a language for a particular project.

Comment: @MaxB: The practical utility of the information is irrelevant; the question is the *quality* of it. There is no definitive answer for "Gorilla vs. Shark", just as there is no definitive answer for "SML vs. OCaml". That's what is wrong with them.

Comment: *"The practical utility of the information is irrelevant"*. Sorry, but you are wrong. I'll quote the official rules to you: *"a **practical**, answerable problem that is unique to software development … then you’re in the right place to ask your question"*

Comment: @MaxB: My point is that the *analogy* is not about the practicality of the information, but the *incompleteness* of it.

Comment: @NicolBolas If you actually clicked on that blog post, you'd see that practical utility is the number 1 concern (which applies to Gorilla vs Shark, but not SML vs OCaml)

Comment: I'd just like to point the irony... You say your question should be fine because 'this old one was fine'. Now... This old one was closed because it is off topic (maybe it wasn't THEN, but it surely is now). Doesn't the fact the question you based yourself of is being closed as off topic a sign that, indeed, such questions aren't for this site?

Comment: @Patrice it was closed after I linked to it (for 8 years, it was fine). Is it "irony"? Ask in english.stackexchange.com

Comment: That blog post mentions practical utility a couple times, but the number one focus is on the _answerability_ of such questions. As it said near the end, there are ways to ask practical, answerable questions that compare two things, but that is quite a fine line, and asking for a comparison of two programming languages is going to be some combination of too broad, unclear, and primarily opinion based.

Comment: @MaxB for 8 years, it slipped under the radar. You flagged it to the most quality minded folk of this community and got a resounding 'no, this isn't on topic'. That is an answer in itself I'd say.

Comment: @TinyGiant just read the answer to SML vs OCaml. It's clear, unopinionated, and as complete as most answers on SO.

Comment: It is not complete. It links to a more complete and anecdotal comparison that is still incomplete. Saying "There are quite a few syntactic differences" is not in any way complete.

Comment: @Patrice I don't see any irony here, and would it make any difference if it were ironic?

Comment: @TinyGiant experienced programmers are not particularly concerned about minor syntactic differences.

Comment: Oh so I'm not an experienced programmer now?

Comment: @TinyGiant I have no idea. I was just making a general (and uncontroversial) observation. Looking at your SO activity, I think you are a programmer. Even if you only know a scripting language like JS, that technically counts as being a programmer, although some people might argue that it's qualitatively different from doing complex algorithms in C++.

Comment: Now you've managed to insult me and the JavaScript community, and you've made a fairly bold assumption about me based on the content of my profile.

Comment: @TinyGiant Well, if I did insult you, that was unintentional. I thought you asked me whether I thought you were an experienced programmer, and the only way I could answer that was by looking at your SO profile. Like I wrote *I* personally think you are, in fact, a programmer, but you have to understand that these distinctions are not clear-cut.

Comment: You said _"experienced programmers are not particularly concerned about minor syntactic differences"_, which implies that all those who _are_ concerned about minor syntactic differences (as I do) are not "experienced programmers"; so I was asking you to clarify or better qualify your statement indirectly by bringing to light the implication of said statement. I did not ask you to make assumptions about my knowledge and competency based on the incomplete information I've chosen to provide in my profile, nor did I ask you to introduce a techno-religious thumb-war to the discussion.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't have any negative feelings about JS. I'm just saying that other people do, for example: https://www.reddit.com/r/programmingcirclejerk/comments/6rbf9o/javascript_virtue_signaling/dl3yksi/

Comment: *"Is there a specific rule that says that comparing languages is off-topic?"* Yes: ["Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). In other words, questions that are too broad for a Q&A format are prohibited and regularly closed.

Comment: @CodyGray the answer was much shorter than a book

Comment: Because it is not complete. And therefore not a good answer by our standards. A complete answer would easily approach book length.

Comment: @CodyGray Something describing SML would be book-length. Something pointing out the differences from OCaml is not.

Comment: @MaxB so stop being pedantic and picking at the 'irony' word I used and try to see the argument I'm trying to make. For someone 'not particularly concerned with minor syntactic differences' you get stuck in a pretty pedantic point over choice of word used. The argument is 'you based the topicality of your question on this old question. Community went ahead and closed old question to indicate it ISN'T on topic. Therefore your thinking that your question is on topic because this old one was doesn't hold anymore'

Comment: @Patrice My question was **not** "Why didn't you close this old question?". It was, in part, "If the policy changed, what are the new rules"? The fact that the old question got closed retroactively is irrelevant and unfortunate for SO, since it was clearly helpful.

Comment: @MaxB how is it irrelevant? " but a question about SML vs OCaml got 81 upvotes in 2009, and the best answer got 136 upvotes."... yes... it's also CLOSED now... so it's completely relevant. You say "If this old question use to be ok, why isn't mine ok too?" and the community showed you clearly that the old question ISN'T ok... what more do you need? I only talked about why the old question wasn't closed when you commented that it was ok for 8 years. My comment was that it WASN'T ok, it just hasn't been noticed.

Answer (score 13):

> if your question ... is **a practical, answerable problem** that is unique to software development then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>   <sup>https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic</sup>

A question asking us to compare two or more things is not a practical, answerable problem. You are asking us to discuss, not to solve a problem. We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed

Comment: but it is answerable (see the answer that got 136 upvotes), and practical (you need to know about the differences if you are deciding which language to learn or use)

Comment: @MaxB: "Answerable" does not mean "you can write something called an 'answer' and get upvotes". An answer needs to be something more than just things a person will upvote. An answer has to be *complete*. And thus, an answerable question is a question that can have answers that are complete. Where looking at one answer can reasonably give you all you need to know. That is not the case for opinion-based questions; one answer will only give you that person's opinion.

Comment: @NicolBolas 136 people felt that it was complete enough, which is why they upvoted it.

Comment: @MaxB: No, they felt that they should upvote it. That doesn't mean that they would say it was complete. People upvote things for many reasons.

Comment: There's a dramatic difference between an answered question and an answerable question. Either way, a question being answered bears absolutely zero relevance to the question's topicality. A great answer can salvage a bad question, sure, but the question has to actually be an on-topic question, @MaxB.

Comment: @fbueckert If something is answered then it was answerable. The reverse is not necessarily true. That's just how English works. english.SE would be the right place to discuss it though, instead of here.

Comment: @MaxB you may want to give a read to [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)